# NAudio: Should I dispose a WaveOut object before each call to the Init method

Tags: naudio

I once read in a tutorial (unfortunately, I can't find where), that if I want to play several audio files, and use `WaveOut`, I should dispose the last `WaveOut` object before calling the `Init` method again. If not, I will get an error. However, I didn't dispose the objects, and everything works. I did this:

```
Mp3FileReader reader_1 = new Mp3FileReader("1.mp3");
Mp3FileReader reader_2 = new Mp3FileReader("2.mp3");

WaveOut WaveOutDevice = new WaveOut();

WaveOutDevice.Init(reader_1);
WaveOutDevice.Play();
```

and after a while, playing a second file:

```
WaveOutDevice.Init(reader_2);
WaveOutDevice.Play();
```

So I just want to be sure that I'm doing the right thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WaveOut` was initially designed for `Init` to only be called a single time. In some circumstances it may work, but I'd recommend creating a new instance of `WaveOut` to play your next sound.

Comment: Ok. But in general, if I make an app like a media player, in which the user select a song to listen to, is it a good practice, in terms of performance, to re-create WaveOut for each time he play a song? And last - should I also re-create the Mp3FileReader, or is it ok to use Position=0 to return to the beginning of the song?

Comment: the thing is, when you open your soundcard, you are choosing sample rate and channel count. So you have to close and reopen to play any subsequent file that isn't at the same sample rate. For repositioning, setting Position = 0 is fine.

Comment: If I ensure that all files have the same sample rate and channel count, do I still need to reopen the sound card? And if the answer is no, does the bit depth must also be the same for all files?

Comment: Yes, bit depth should be the same as well